# DMF/DIXF AX 2012 R3 Custom generate method

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm working around File Exchange (Export) using `Data Import Export Framework` (DIXF) , i want to add generate method to Find `LineAmount` Purchline associated with the receiving line `VendPackingSlipTrans`  from `PurchLine` table.I create the following script but i need a help :

```
[DMFTargetTransformationAttribute(true),DMFTargetTransformationDescAttribute("Function that generate LineAmount"),
 DMFTargetTransformationSequenceAttribute(11),
 DMFTargetTransFieldListAttribute([fieldStr(DMFVendPackingSlipTransEntity,LineAmount)])
]
public container GenerateLineAmount(boolean _stagingToTarget = true)
{

    container                  res;
    PurchLine                  purchLine;
    VendPackingSlipTrans       vendPackingSlipTrans;

    if (_stagingToTarget)
    {
        select firstOnly purchLine
            where purchLine.LineAmount                  == entity.LineAmount &&
                  vendPackingSlipTrans.OrigPurchid      == purchLine.PurchId &&
                  vendPackingSlipTrans.PurchaseLineLineNumber == purchLine.LineNumber;

        if ( ! purchLine )
        {
            entity.LineAmount = purchLine.LineAmount ;
            entity.insert();
        }
    }
    res = [entity.LineAmount];
    return res;
}
```

I have to export data from ax to file using DMF,so for that i have some field existing in VendPackingSlipTrans so added this fields in staging table but others field exist in other table like LineAmount.I don't know how to add this others fields in staging table. for that in myEnityclass i create generat method to associate field in source table. to staging table

Comment: What help do you need?

Comment: "How do I associate vendor product receipt lines (VendPackingSlipTrans) with purchase lines (PurchLine)?"...  Is that the question?

Comment: The select statement and the following logic to set field `LineAmount` does not make any sense. As it is currently written, `LineAmount` will always be zero because the select statement will retrieve a `PurchLine` record with an empty `PurchId` and a `LineNumber` of zero (because the `vendPackingSlipTrans` variable is never instantiated) and unless you have corrupt data, such a `PurchLine` record should not exist. Also it doesn't make sense to call `entity.insert()` in this method. `Generate` methods are used to set one field of the entity record, not to insert the entity record.

Comment: @ian_scho Yes and get value of `LineAmount` because i want this value in staging table

Comment: @FH-Inway can you help to correct this select statement

Comment: @Astoner: I'm still trying to understand what you are trying to do. It seems you to want to import `VendPackingSlipTrans` records (which is not a good idea in itself), but your source (whatever that is) cannot provide a line amount (but then why do the import in the first place if such a central information is missing?). So instead you want to use the line amount of the purchase order line. You would need the `InventTransId` of the purchase order line for that, but your source probably does not have this information. If these guesses are correct, you may want to reconsider your requirements.

Comment: @FH-Inway I have to export data from ax to file using DMF,so for that i have some field existing in `VendPackingSlipTrans` so added this fields in `staging table` but others field exist in other table like `LineAmount`.I don't know how to add this others fields in staging table. for that in myEnityclass i create generat method to associate field in source table. to staging table

Comment: @Astoner: Please move the information you have provided in the comments into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems you want to export `VendPackingSlipTrans` records with additional information from `PurchLine` records using a custom entity of the data import/export-Framework (DIXF). If that is correct, there are several problems in your implementation:

1. logic in `if (_stagingToTarget)` branch: since the framework can be used for both import and export, `_stagingToTarget` is used to distinguish between the two. If `_stagingToTarget` is `true`, data is imported from the staging table to the Dynamics AX target table. So you need to put the logic in the `else` branch.
2. selection of `PurchLine` record: the current implementation will never select a `PurchLine` record because values of an uninstantiated `VendPackingSlipTrans` table variable are used as criteria in the select statement. Also the chosen criteria are wrong, take a look at method `purchLine` of table `VendPackingSlipTrans` to see how to get the `PurchLine` record for a `VendPackingSlipTrans` record and use the `target` variable to instantiate the `VendPackingSlipTrans` table variable.
3. check `if (! purchLine)`: This check means that if NO `PurchLine` record could be found with the previous select statement, the `LineAmount` of this empty record will be used for the staging record. This is wrong, instead you want to use the `LineAmount` of a record that has been found.
4. `entity.insert()`: as I mentioned in the comments, the entity record should not be inserted in a generate method; the framework will take care of the insert

A possible fix of these problems could look like this:

```cs
[
    DMFTargetTransformationAttribute(true),
    DMFTargetTransformationDescAttribute('function that determines LineAmount for export'),
    DMFTargetTransformationSequenceAttribute(11),
    DMFTargetTransFieldListAttribute([fieldStr(DMFVendPackingSlipTransEntity, LineAmount)])
]
public container GenerateLineAmount(boolean _stagingToTarget = true)
{
    container                  res;
    PurchLine                  purchLine;
    VendPackingSlipTrans       vendPackingSlipTrans;

    if (_stagingToTarget)
    {
        // this will be executed during import
        res = [0.0];
    }
    else
    {
        // this will be executed during export
        // the target variable contains the VendPackingSlipTrans that is exported
        vendPackingSlipTrans = target;
        purchLine = vendPackingSlipTrans.purchLine();
        if (purchLine)
        {
            res = [purchLine.LineAmount];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you you are the best , your explication help me to learn new things

Comment: I get the following  error when i try to test my export by create a new Target entities in Data import export framword>Target entities :`Error executing code: DMFVendPackingSlipTransClass object does not have method getFieldsSequence` I want to answer new question,but i have reached my question limit sorry for that

Comment: @Astoner: take a look how other DIXF entity classes implement this method, e.g. `DMFPurchLineEntityClass`. This should give you an idea how you can implement the method in your own `DMFVendPackingSlipTransClass`.

Comment: Thank you , i fixed my error  i forget extends DMFEntityBase for my class